# What is the application size impact of using Realm DB in Swift on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-database

I recently came across Realm DB for Swift iOS, and it looks very promising. With this said, after importing the library, the app looks like it's taking about 48 MB of storage on the device, despite very minimal code being included in the app. Is this expected behaviour for Realm DB?

I have not been able to find much other than that the frameworks included are about 80MB and 15MB for Realm.framework and RealmSwift.framework (these are what you drag into XCode to install)

SQlite appears to be still under 1MB; is it expected that this framework will use many times that space?

I'm wondering what the application size increase associated with using Realm DB should be for iOS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> **How big is the Realm base library?**
>
> Realm should only add around 5 to 8 MB to your app’s download size.
>   The releases we distribute are significantly larger because they
>   include support for the iOS, watchOS and tvOS simulators, some debug
>   symbols, and bitcode, all of which are stripped by the App Store
>   automatically when apps are downloaded.

Reference:
[Realm's Swift Documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest#faq)